# How can I assign the default Ansible value when environment variable does not exist?

Tags: ansible, environment-variables

My goal is to have a flexible Ansible role where the value of a variable can be provided in this order of precedence (greatest to least):

1. from the command line using '--extra-vars'
2. from environment variables
3. from the defaults in the role

1 & 3 match the order of precedence documented for Ansible variables (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable), so I have focused my attention on the environment variables.  Using the `lookup('env',...)` plugin, I am able to read in the environment variable in the `vars/main.yml` and the precedence order is exactly what I want.

However, when the environment variable is not defined, the `lookup` plugin returns an empty string.  This means that the variable is assigned the empty string instead of remaining undefined so that the default value can be assigned.

**Playbook (var-exp.yml)**

```
- name: Variable experiment
  hosts: all

  tasks:
  - import_role:
      name: ansible-role-variable-experiment
```

**Role (ansible-role-variable-experiment)**

*tasks/main.yml*

```
- name: Display value of 'location'
  debug:
    msg: 'location is {{ location }}'
```

*defaults/main.yml*

```
location: from-defaults-main-yml
```

*vars/main.yml*

```
# If used, this will override the value in defaults/main.yml, as expected
# location: from-vars-main-yml

# Since lookup returns '' when the environment variable doesn't exist,
# location gets set to '' instead of being left undefined so that the
# default can be used:
# location: "{{ lookup('env', 'LOCATION' ) }}"  # -> location == ''

# When the environment variable does not exist, all of these options generate 
# some value assigned to location so that the default cannot be assigned:
# location: "{{ lookup('env', 'LOCATION' ) | default(None, true) }}"  # -> location == ''
# location: "{{ lookup('env', 'LOCATION' ) | default(omit, true) }}"  # -> location == __omit_place_holder__3e8bdbb6cebc653a758afca99607fcf9ec1f99f4
# location: "{{ lookup('env', 'LOCATION' ) | default('undefined') }}"  # -> location == ''
# location: "{{ lookup('env', 'LOCATION' ) | reject('undefined') }}"  # -> location == <generator object select_or_reject at 0x10caaef00>

# When the environment variable does not exist, these generate a recursive 
# loop that crashes the play:
# location: "{{ lookup('env', 'LOCATION' ) | default(location) }}"
# location: "{{ lookup('env', 'LOCATION' ) | default(location, true) }}"
```

**Execution Examples**

With environment variable:

```
LOCATION=from-env-variable ansible-playbook ./var-exp.yml
```

Without environment variable:

```
ansible-playbook ./var-exp.yml
```

I have not been able to identify a clean way to accomplish my goal.  I have been able to come up with a way to "work around" this:

*vars/main.yml*

```
default_location: from-default-array-in-vars-main-yml

location: "{{ lookup('env', 'LOCATION' ) | default(default_location, true) }}"
```

And while this seems to accomplish what I want, now I am defining "defaults" in the "vars" area instead of in "defaults" area.

The Ansible documentation says something like "if you are doing something that seems too complicated, it probably is."

***So, my question is:*** Is there an easier/better/correct way to accomplish this? Or, have I run into a limitation in the way Ansible 2.4.2 (or the `lookup('env')` plugin) is currently implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do it using a single variable name.

The only workaround I can think of is using `set_fact`:

```
- set_fact:
    location: "{{ lookup('env', 'LOCATION' ) | ternary (lookup('env', 'LOCATION' ), omit) }}"
```

This way if environment variable `LOCATION` does not exist/is empty, the task will not assign a value (`omit`) and the default from the role will be used (i.e. it will not get overridden).

You could either run place it in `pre_tasks` before roles are called, or at the top of roles `tasks/main.yml`

---

Rationale:

The whole problem you brought is using a single variable name throughout the process, but:

- variables in Ansible are lazy-evaluated
- once you define a variable in the `vars` section, it has precedence over the one defined in `defaults` (even though evaluation will take place later - lookup plugin is irrelevant to the problem)
- there is no way to undefine variable in Ansible

Ansible processes the "precedence chain" for variables (before running any task) and once it encounters a definition, it stops. There is no further "going back" at execution time, when the actual values are evaluated.

---

Remark:

> I have been able to come up with a way to "work around" this:
>
> [ ]
>
> now I am defining "defaults" in the "vars" area instead of in "defaults" area.

But you don't have to. There is no requirement to put your `default_location` variable into `vars`. You can define it in `defaults` (the value is used at the execution time).

Comment: First of all, thank you—your workaround does, indeed, work.

Comment: I'm afraid I may not be understanding the "single variable name" issue.  What I want is to be able to use a variable (let's say `path_to_file_destination`) in the tasks in the role (since the process is the same regardless of the defined path).  However, I want to (1) have a default path defined in the role, (2) let someone using this role be able to define this path in an environment variable and (3) let them temporarily override either of these values by providing --extra-vars.  Are you saying I should use differently named variables for each of these?

Comment: If you use `location` and `default_location` — you use two variables and no problem. If you insist on using a single variable name (`locacion`) then the problem of overriding the default precedence arises.

Comment: Ah. Got it. Thanks!